# The GNU Debugger - Package operation failed

Tags: update-manager

When I try to update the GNU Debugger using the update-manager, I get the following error:

> "Package operation failed. The installation or removal of a software package failed."

The output message is:

```
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 384037 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gdb 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2 (using.../gdb_7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gdb ...dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb_7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py', which is also in package gdb-msp430 7.2~mspgcc-7.2-20110612-1ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb_7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will have to remove gdb-msp430, as it can not be installed at the same time as regular gdb.  You also should file a bug report against that package because it either should state that it conflicts with gdb, and thus, gdb would be removed instead of giving this error, or it should be fixed so that it does not conflict.

Comment: This conflicting file seems to be [removed in Quantal for `gdb-msp430`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/gdb-msp430/filelist).